# How to add/combine output to existing an array in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

My `$file` contains two columns. Using the username in `.`, I would like to add `name` and `givenname` as the third and fourth columns respectively.  So far I have:

```
$file = Import-Csv H:\computers2userswoSP1.csv
$out = foreach ($o in $file.name) {
    Get-ADUser $o | select name, givenname
}
```

I tried adding the code below into the first `foreach`, but that didn't work:

```
foreach ($r in $out) {
    New-Object PSObject -prop @{
        name = $file.fullname
        givenname = $file.Firstname
    }
}
```

and also adding this before the loops:

```
Add-Member -InputObject $file -TypeName fullname
Add-Member -InputObject $file -TypeName Firstname
```

with this in the loop:

```
$out.givenname += $file.FirstName
$out.name += $file.
```

As you can see, I'm shooting in the dark a little. Any recommendations?

Comment: So what do you want `$out` to be?  A custom object? A multidimensional array where each object in the array is another array with a set of values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the file, pipe to select, select all of its properties and add two more. This will create blank properties which you can update inside the loop.

The import command ([Import-Csv](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx)) is in parentheses so you can update the file. Without it, the file will be in use and the update will fail.

One thing though. It looks like you already have a Name column in your file, so I named the new property 'fullname'.

```
(Import-Csv H:\computers2userswoSP1.csv | select *, Name, GivenName) | ForEach-Object{
    $user = Get-ADUser $_.name | select fullname, givenname
    $_.fullname = $user.name
    $_.givenname = $user.firstname
    $_
} | Export-Csv H:\computers2userswoSP1.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

If I read your intentions correctly, you want to add two properties to each object produced by [`Import-Csv`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx) based on data from [AD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory). If that is the case, you can do something like (here `Import-Csv` is emulated by [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849890.aspx)):

```
@'
username,fullname
bielawb,"Bartek Bielawki"
fasolaj,"Jas Fasola"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | foreach {
    $AD = Get-ADUser -Identity $_.username
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        UserName = $_.username
        FullName = $_.fullname
        Name = $AD.Name
        GivenName = $AD.GivenName
    }
}
```

Data in CSV is irrelevant; if fields do not match the one you have in your CSV, just update values in the [`New-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849885.aspx) syntax.